# CSS Inner Div Fill Outer Div

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and have a question about expanding the content of an inner DIV to fill the entire outer div.

I have been researching an answer to my problem for hours and have found dozens of similar questions, but none of the suggested solutions work for me.  I'm sure it's that I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

I need to have the blue background cover the entire block between "Some other stuff" and "More different stuff" and the text must be centered vertically and horizontally in the blue block - and maintain the same hover qualities and `text-decoration` rules.

```
<div>
    <span>Some other stuff</span>
</div
<div class="outer-container">
    <h2>
        <a class="inner-container" href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
            Lorem ipsum
        </a>
    </h2>
</div>
<div>
    More different stuff
</div>
```

I have so much trouble with CSS because I don't know how to gracefully describe what I'm wanting - I'm a developer not a designer!

```
.outer-container {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: x-large;
  &:focus, &:hover, &:link {
    background-color: #286090;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

If I put the `focus`, `hover` CSS stuff in the `outer-container` the hover mechanics are not consistent.

I hope I'm making sense...like I said, I have a horrible time explaining design stuff.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set background color to `outer-container`.

When you set `background-color` to `<a>` tag, the background color is assigned to the text only.

Here is you updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr9m6k16/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```css
.outer-container {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  background: #337AB7;
}
.inner-container {
  background-color: #337AB7;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

```html
<div> <span>Some other stuff</span>

</div>
<div class="outer-container"> <a class="inner-container" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vestibulum purus vel iaculis accumsan. Nulla vel massa velit. Proin a nisl vel tortor tincidunt pharetra. Nulla tristique porttitor erat. In laoreet, erat non ultricies vulputate, massa mauris tempor ligula, sed dignissim ex augue sit amet sapien. Donec malesuada massa eget turpis consectetur, at feugiat velit aliquam. Fusce dictum ornare dignissim. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer non consectetur nunc, at sollicitudin nibh.</a>

</div>
<div>More different stuff</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this was the solution to my question.  Unfortunately, my actual problem was a bit more complicated that my question and this didn't solve it.  :(  +1 for the solution to the original question - but I'm going to update to include everything.

Answer (score 1):

Why can you not change the background colour to be on the parent `.outer-container`?

This would solve your immediate issue.

See http://jsfiddle.net/n1gva5b4/

Answer (score 1):

If a was you i would make a div-container and inside the div(innerContainer) insert the a-link-tag. So the Conainer does what its called (contain-something), applies the color as you want it and the link also works fine.

like this:

```
<div class="outer-container">
     <div class="inner-container" >
        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the outer-container responses don't help, an alternative is to set `display: block` on inner-container. Block-level elements are the ones that take up all available horizontal space on their parent by default (an example might be, one of these answers), and "inline-level" elements like `a` (by default anyway) can be placed in the middle of a block of text, only affecting its own text without re-flowing any layout around it.